# Rename a jar file removing the version number

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to rename a jar file name with a version embedded in it like 
`test-java-1.0.0.jar` to `test-java.jar`

Tried below approach but this will not workout if the version is changed to something like

`test-java-11.0.0.jar` or `test-compile-1.0.12.jar`

```
Set test=test-java-1.0.0.jar
set test1=%test:~0,-10%
rename %test% %test1%.jar
```

Looking for something like:

Input string: `test-java-1.0.0.jar`

Expected output: `test-java.jar`

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ("%test%") do ren %test% %%a-%%b.jar`

Comment: Thanks AAcini this works for the file name test-java-1.0.0.jar. The files names can be any something like compile-java-1.11.1.jar, poc-java-1.2.22.jar, some-thing-1.2.32.jar. So, I need to rename them without  a version number.

Comment: In your question you specified that the base name is stored in the `test` variable and that you want to "rename a jar file"... Do you want a _general_ method that works over all file names? If so: `for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B *-*-*.jar') do ren "%%a-%%b-%%c.jar" "%%a-%%b.jar"`

Comment: The files names can be any something more like compile-java-code-1.11.1.jar,             poc-java-compile-1.2.22.jar, some-thing-like-1.2.32.jar. So, I need to rename them without  a version number.

Comment: Then, why you didn't say that in the question? Sorry, but we are not mind readers... **`:(`**

Comment: I am learning understood will provide more details, 1st time contributor on this space. Thanks Aacini

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough

```
ren test-java*.jar test-java.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the response montonero, i don't wan't to hard code it as I have different file names and I may run it in a loop, I am looking for some thing in that can filter out the version and rename the files like compile-java-1.11.1.jar to compile-java.jar, poc-java-1.2.22.jar to poc-java.jar, some-thing-1.2.32.jar to some-thing.jar.

Comment: Then please describe it more precisely in your question.

Comment: Sure montonero, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To strip any characters `0-9.-_` from the back of the file name without extension:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\05\30\SO_56380430.cmd
@Echo off
for %%A in (
    "test java-1.0.0.jar"
    compile-java-1.11.1.jar
    poc-java-1.2.22.jar
    some-thing-1.2.32.jar
) do call :StripVer "%%~A"

Goto :Eof

:StripVer
set "Name=%~n1"
:loop
Echo %Name:~-1%|findstr "[0-9._-]" >Nul && (set "Name=%Name:~0,-1%"&Goto :loop)
Echo Original name : %~1
Echo w/o version   : %Name%%~x1
Echo:
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\30\SO_56380430.cmd
Original name : test java-1.0.0.jar
w/o version   : test java.jar

Original name : compile-java-1.11.1.jar
w/o version   : compile-java.jar

Original name : poc-java-1.2.22.jar
w/o version   : poc-java.jar

Original name : some-thing-1.2.32.jar
w/o version   : some-thing.jar
```

This method is quite slow.

A one liner in PowerShell will be a lot faster.

```
Get-ChildItem *.jar|Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename.trimend('0123456789.-_')+$_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

Remove the trailing `-WhatIf` if the output looks OK.

That could be wrapped in cmd line /batch file

```
powershell -Nop -C "Get-ChildItem *.jar|Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename.trimend('0123456789.-_')+$_.Extension} -WhatIf"
```

Comment: Batch script worked as expected but not for the file name with spaces like "test java compile.jar. Can this be extended for it, I have tried making few changes but returns undesired results. The powershell one works well but I am I need to use batch script.

Comment: Applied some small changes regarding quoting to the batch.

Answer (score 0):

This method works removing *the last part* of the file name separated by hypen:

**EDIT 2019/05/31**: *Support for filenames with spaces added*

```
@echo off

for %%f in (
  test-java-1.0.0.jar
  compile-java-1.11.1.jar
  poc-java-1.2.22.jar
  compile-java-code-1.11.1.jar
  poc-java-compile-1.2.22.jar
  some-thing-like-1.2.32.jar
  "test java-1.0.0.jar"
  "compile java test-1.2.22.jar"
) do call :Rename %%f
goto :EOF


:Rename name

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "old=%~1"
set "new=" & set "x=%old:-=" & set "new=!new!-!x!" & set "x=%"
echo REN "%old%" "%new:~1%.jar"
exit /B
```

Sample output:

```
REN "test-java-1.0.0.jar" "test-java.jar"
REN "compile-java-1.11.1.jar" "compile-java.jar"
REN "poc-java-1.2.22.jar" "poc-java.jar"
REN "compile-java-code-1.11.1.jar" "compile-java-code.jar"
REN "poc-java-compile-1.2.22.jar" "poc-java-compile.jar"
REN "some-thing-like-1.2.32.jar" "some-thing-like.jar"
REN "test java-1.0.0.jar" "test java.jar"
REN "compile java test-1.2.22.jar" "compile java test.jar"
```

To really rename the files, remove the `echo` command before `REN` part.

Comment: Thanks Aacini, script works like a charm. Can this be extended to file names with spaces in like "test java-1.0.0.jar" or "compile java test-1.2.22.jar".                          The existing script when used the out put - "test" "~1.jar"
"java-1.0.0.jar" "java.jar".

Comment: Yes, see my edit... If you would specified from the very beginning all these details on your filenames, then this continuous _"Can the code be modified for this new requirement I didn't specified before?"_ would be avoided...  **`:(`**